# ios - Reachability notifications multiple alerts

Tags: ios, uialertview, reachability

I'm using Tony Million's version of Reachability (problem was the same with Apple's version of Reachability) to check on my app if there is an active internet connection.

Here is what I want:
when the view loads or appears, it checks if there is an internet connection. if there isn't any, if shows an alert, and on click, it tries again, until there is an active connection.

If there is a connection, the view is loaded normally. When Reachability notifies of connection loss, it displays the same alert again.
Here is my actual code:

```
//in the implementation:
BOOL internetActivated;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self testInternetConnection];
    NSLog(@"%d", internetActivated);
    if(internetActivated == NO)
    {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pas de connexion internet" message:@"Une connexion est requise pour utiliser l'application" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Réessayer", nil];
        [alert show]; 
    }
    else {
        [self onAppearFunction];
    }
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self testInternetConnection];
    if(internetActivated == NO)
    {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pas de connexion internet" message:@"Une connexion est requise pour utiliser l'application" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Réessayer", nil];
        [alert show]; 
    }
    else {
        [self onAppearFunction];
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
}

- (void)testInternetConnection
{
    __unsafe_unretained typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    internetReachableFoo = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

    // Internet is reachable
    internetReachableFoo.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            internetActivated = YES;
            NSLog(@"Yayyy, we have the interwebs!");
        });
    };

    // Internet is not reachable
    internetReachableFoo.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            internetActivated = NO;
            UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pas de connexion internet" message:@"Une connexion est requise pour utiliser l'application" delegate:weakSelf cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Réessayer", nil];
            [alert show];
            NSLog(@"Someone broke the internet :(");
        });
    };

    [internetReachableFoo startNotifier];
}
```

Multiple problems:
1) InternetActivated starts as "NO", even though I call `[self testInternetConnection]` before testing the if condition. It should be updated to *YES*, shouldn't it?

2) Even when I have internet connection, the `UIAlertView` inside the `testInternetConnection` method keeps getting called. Actually: three or four times the second alert gets called (inside the testInternet method), and then three or four times the first alert view gets called, the one inside the `viewDidLoad` method.

By the way, I noticed that this NSLog: `NSLog(@"Yayyy, we have the interwebs!");`
gets called more than one time on every [self testInternetConnection] call.

I'm completely messing the alert calls up and it's driving me crazy!

Thanks for your help

UPDATE:

I managed to avoid the multiple alert by setting a BOOL to true when it's loaded and false when it gets clicked away to avoid multiple alerts from stacking up. Only thing is I want the `internetActivated` BOOL to be updated before I check it in the if...

Comment: Of course I will once it works well ! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the code from viewdidload

```
Bool alertIsShowing = NO;

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (! alertIsShowing)
        [self testInternetConnection];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    alertIsShowing = NO;
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        [self testInternetConnection];
    }
}

- (void)testInternetConnection
{
    __unsafe_unretained typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    internetReachableFoo = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

    // Internet is reachable
    internetReachableFoo.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Yayyy, we have the interwebs!");
            [self onAppearFunction];
        });
    };

    // Internet is not reachable
    internetReachableFoo.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pas de connexion internet" message:@"Une connexion est requise pour utiliser l'application" delegate:weakSelf cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Réessayer", nil];
            [alert show];
            alertIsShowing = YES;
            NSLog(@"Someone broke the internet :(");
        });
    };

    [internetReachableFoo startNotifier];
}
```

Comment: I apologize for all that editing. try this now. what do you get?

Comment: you are calling [self viewDidLoad]; on clickedButtonAtIndex!

Comment: Couple of things. The [self viewDidLoad] in the alertview is there to try again when the user presses "Try again" (in French). When I take it away, it doesn't load again. I don't want the view to load until there is an internet connection. 
Two problems: when I load the view for the first time it displays the alert (because internetActivated is NO, I can't change it...). And second problem: when internet is turned off and on again, it displays the alert view from the testInternetConnection method four times again...

Comment: Thanks. When I disable internet and turn it on again, I get SEVEN (!!!!) NSLog's that tell me "Someone broke the internet :(". That's why I get so many alerts! But I don't understand how it's possible.

Comment: Here is your explanation. you load the page. alert shows, then you go to connect the internet. when you get back view appear again. thats another call for the alert. you click the button on the first alert. it call viewdidload method. and then you click on the alert button and that another call. and so on. thats a wrong approach.

Comment: I fixed the code you have with your approach. try it please.

Comment: Yes this works, almost. Only problem: internetActivated is "NO" by default. And when I do [self testConnection] it doesn't get updated to YES the first time, so I always get an alert when I load the view. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Fixed everything now.